# Postgres C extension aggregate: How to detect first time aggregate function is called

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm writing a C extension aggregate function for PostgreSQL , and in C code I would like to know if it is the first time that transition function of the aggregate be called.

For example, I define a aggregate function such as:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE my_aggregate (text) (
sfunc = my_transfunc,
stype = text,
finalfunc = my_finalfn,
initcond = '');
```

Then in C code of **my_transfunc**, how can I know if it is the first time my_transfunc be called ( but not the second, third ... time).

```
Datum my_transfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
      // How to check if the first time function called
      if (first_time) { then do something }
      else { do some other things }
}
```

I don't want to use global or static variable here as this made my function is not threaded-safe which violent the requirement for my function.

Comment: Since PostgreSQL is single-threaded, you don't have to worry about thread-safety.

Comment: A global or static variable may cause chaos in multiple parallel instances of the function (two the same aggregates in a single query).

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is a matter of a proper setting of `initcond`. Typically you do not need to know whether the function is executed for the first time if only the algorithm is designed properly.

In your case, assuming that the function returns non-empty string, you can check whether the argument is empty (i.e. is equal to `initcond`). Of course, you can set `initcond` to a special value instead of an empty string.

```
Datum my_transfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    text *arg = PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP(0);
    int32 arg_size = VARSIZE_ANY_EXHDR(arg);

    if (arg_size == 0) { // arg == initcond }
    else { // do some other things }
}
```